# Quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Electrons are wave packets in quantum field theory.The process in which there is an exchange of electrons between materials in quantum field theory can be described as the exchange of wave packets?

Comment: By *exchange of electrons* do you mean exchange of virtual particles during a scattering process, or do you mean real electrons moving between different bound states? If you mean the latter that isn't something QFT does particularly well.

Comment: Real electrons. I just want to understand whether it is possible to exchange electrons in QFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A field theory has little to do with the wave behaviour of elementary particles. It is in fact the quantum mechanics that postulates elementary particles as entities with wave-like properties. A field is a concept that is useful in many fields of physics and you don't necessarily have just "particle" fields. Fields are in fact just tools to describe energy transfer and forces acting on some distance.

Imagine you have a space - a sheet of paper with coordinate lines drawn. Now fill this paper with points and assign some number to each point you draw. This is how you visualise a field. You can think of a field as a function that gives you some number for every point in space. 
An example is a temperature field - you can assign every point in your room a number in degrees of celsius or farenheit(whichever you prefer).

A field that assigns a number to each point in space is called a scalar field - because numbers in mathematics are called scalars. You can also have a field that gives you a vector - an arrow - for every point in space - an example of this kind of field is wind: for wind in atmosphere, you can assign a direction where the wind is blowing and a speed or force with which it is blowing.

Electromagnetic field given by Maxwell's equations in classical electrodynamics are fields. Electromagnetism are just numbers that arise from these equations for every point in space.

Field theory looks at different particles as different fields. Meaning that singular particles make little sense in field theory because it is all just some numbers in every point of a space. The particle field has some ground value if you do not pump energy into it, which we call a vacuum. If you do pump some energy into the field, you can excite it and create a particle. So particles in field theory in general are really just bunches of energy pumped into some kind of field. You can have "photons" as vector fields of electric and magnetic vectors in classical field theory, that is really just a flow of energy from one place to another. You can also have nonzero classical field even if you don't pump any energy into it: for example pernament magnets.
You can have a magnet that stays magnetic forever and does not require any energy to stay magnetic.

By interaction in any field theory(classical or quantum) we usually mean just transfer of energy between different kinds of fields.

Now enter the "new" physics - relativity and quantum. Relativity tells us, that matter is just a form of energy and vice versa. This fact changes our perception of physical fields. Now physical fields, which are just a transfer of energy, are as real as the energy they transfer. Knowing this fact and given sufficient amount of energy, we can ask ourselves, can we turn this abstract field into some tangible matter? Quantum field theory says yes, we can.

Quantum field theory views particles as an universal fields. Particles are always there and are everywhere - vacuum is a sea of particles in some ground states. Pump it enough energy and you can excite this vacuum into tangible particles that you can measure.

But just because you have a vacuum it does not mean you have no field. A vacuum in field theory can have some nonzero field, in quantum field theory it has two kinds of nonzero fields: you can have a nonzero field vacuum like the example with pernament magnet - it just has some number in every point in space. Usually we have the freedom to set this value to something, but there is one elementary field that we can not do this - that is the case of the weird Higgs field. It has something to do with the function that governs behaviour of this field - it has multiple ground states, multiple "vacuums".

With quantum physics, field theory also acquires some weird nuances. Because in quantum physics, there is the famous heisenberg's uncertainty relation, which can be "transformed" to not speak about momentum and position, but about time and energy, you can create particles from literally nothing given sufficiently short times. This is another kind of particles you can have even in the absolute vacuum.

Both of these facts give rise to the so-called "vacuum energy" and make the quantum world so weird and complicated. It is not just the waves, it is much deeper and weirder.

Comment: In accordance with the quantum field theory, the particle is a stable excitation in the field. I would like to see if the materials can exchange these excitations, for example, electrons in an electric discharge or in chemical processes?
Many physicists claim that everything is created from the fields, and all particles are excitation in the field.

Comment: Well, in quantum mechanics in general "created" is a bad word, since you can not really distinguish between particles and you could say that a particle is "destroyed" and "created" every small time interval it lives. You can't really know if it is another created particle or the same particle. In field theory, my point was, that it also makes little sense to talk about creation because you are just changing some values of some field in some points of space. What makes sense to talk about is the energy flow.

Comment: I would like to know whether materials can exchange these excitations, for example, by electrons in an electric discharge or in chemical processes?

Comment: If you consider the excitation as an unit/quantum of energy, then yes, they exchange these excitations.

Comment: that is, electricity is explained, for example, in Quantum field theory how the motion of these disturbances (electrons)?

Comment: Well, electricity is beyond the scope of QFT's usefulness. With QFT, you want to describe simple interactions between small number of particles on extremely short scales(you could say interactions in just one point of space). Even those simple interactions are extremely difficult to calculate. With electricity you would need to account for the fields of the wire/conductor, the dielectric it is surrounded etc. You could do that, but it does not have any advantage compared to classical approach.

Comment: but from the phenomenological point of view, yes, you should think of electricity as of flows and changes in electron fields